# Visual Studio 2017 MSBUILD giving TS1005 error on typescript ES6 syntax

Tags: typescript, msbuild

I have below code in place, which uses below ES6 syntax in a TS file settings.ts,

```
var text = objectStruct?.property1;
```

While building the project this line gives error as,

```
longpath\settings.ts(197,66): error TS1005: Build:':' expected. [path\myproject.csproj]
```

Typescript build selected in project is to use TypeScript 2.5
I understand this syntax is supported from TS 3 or more. But **if a higher version of typescript is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\ can we override this error?**
Without changing any project settings?

```
Ofcourse error goes away if we fall back to simple syntax condition? truthvalue : falsevalue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a research found the solution.

Project Typescript Build properties my project was referring to 2.5 as I mentioned above. In MicrosoftDKs location I had higher version.

> Open Visual Studio Installer> modify 2017 > Unselect Typescript version 2.5
> Click Save changes

Now this version is removed and msbuild defaulted to highest available without making Project reference changes.

Another alternative if you want you can upgrade from TypescriptBuild properties to "Use Latest Version" option instead of specifying any version. Make sure you are aware of any compatibility issues.